# Draw shape from Class

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I can add a shape to the MainWindow when I place my drawing code in the code behind window. Works fine.

However, when I try to create a class for the shape and include a draw method it does not work.

I've tried 'Inherits MainWindow' using 'StackPanel.Children.Add(Shape)' to add ("draw") the defined shape. No errors are thrown but the shape does not appear in the MainWindow's stackpanel. I've also tried adding 'Imports ProjectName.MainWindow' for the class but it still won't work. There is no visual indication that the shape was added.

I wand to encapsulate different shapes in their own class's with each class having it's own drawing method.

i.e.

```
dim rect as New classRectangle
'another class method sets the values
rect.draw

dim eps as New classElipse
'another class method sets the values
eps.draw
```

etc.

Can this be done and how? Also, any recommended reading on the correct way to do this.

tks

Comment: Is the shape really added to the `StackPanel` as desired? More code sample would facilitate answering.

Comment: I have marked your previous question as duplicate. See the answer given in the linked question for how to add shapes in a proper MVVM solution. If necessary you could extend the solution to also support other shapes. There are a plenty of similar questions and answers on StackOverflow, all using an ItemsControl with an appropriate ItemsPanel, ItemContainerStyle and ItemTemplate.

Comment: Clemens. I'm assuming that the question is complete for wpf code behind and not marking it answered until I can figure out the following. I expect class's to work the same in wpf & winforms in vb. Maybe I'm wrong.  It appears the answer given in other post only works in code behind. What do I need to add to a class so that it can access the wpf form as indicated in this question?

Comment: The 'many answers' all appear to use the Mainwindows code behind form.

Comment: Ok, thanks. MVVM gave brought me to the realization that I really must forget about winforms way of programming.